# Singularities of $z^{2/3}$

Tags: complex-analysis

I am trying to figure out whether $\infty$ is an essential singularity of $z^{2/3}$. Letting $z=\frac{1}{w}$, we have $f(1/w)=(1/w)^{2/3}$, which has a singularity at $w=0$. To determine the order, I consider the following limit:

$$\lim\limits_{w\rightarrow 0}w(1/w)^{2/3}=\lim\limits_{w\rightarrow 0}w^{1/3}=0$$

Since the limit exists, my guess would be that $z\rightarrow \infty$ is not an essential singularity. However, WolframAlpha lists it as [an essential singularity](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=singularities+of+z%5E%282%2F3%29). I also don't know what to make of the fact that the limit is not a nonzero number.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The singularity of $z^{2/3}$ at $\infty$ isn't an isolated singularity: it arises because you need to make a branch cut to define $z^{2/3}$, so that $z^{2/3}$ is not analytic on a punctured neighborhood of $\infty$. Thus, it shouldn't be called an essential singularity. I would argue it shouldn't be called a singularity at all, since these usually refer to the isolated variety, I would just call it a point on the branch cut.

Answer (score 2):

It is not a singularity, but rather a *branch point*. The "function" $1/w^{2/3}$ is not defined in any punctured neighborhood of $w=0$. The "function" $z^{2/3}$ also has another branch point at $z=0$, and those are the only two branch points.

Comment: Would it be wrong to say that $z=0$ is a zero then?

Comment: @sodiumnitrate I would avoid saying that, because it would be misleading. In general, the value of a multi-valued function at a branch point is not well-defined, but in this case all of the branches take the value $0$ at the branch point $z=0$.